# How to solve $(3\lambda^2 + 4\lambda + 6)(2\lambda^2 + \lambda + 7) - 36 = 0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Could you help me?

I have system 
$\begin{cases} 3x'' + 4x' + 6x - 6y = 0 \\ 2y'' + y' - 6x + 7y =0 \end{cases}$

I do:

$det(A\lambda^2 + B\lambda + C) = 0, $

$A = \begin{pmatrix} 3 & 0 \\ 0 & 2 \end{pmatrix}, $
$B = \begin{pmatrix} 4 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}, $
$C = \begin{pmatrix} 6 & -6 \\ -6 & 7 \end{pmatrix}$

$det\begin{pmatrix} 3\lambda^2 + 4\lambda + 6 & -6 \\ -6 & 2\lambda^2 + \lambda + 7 \end{pmatrix} = 0$

$(3\lambda^2 + 4\lambda + 6)(2\lambda^2 + \lambda + 7) - 36 = 0$

$6\lambda^4 + 11\lambda^3 + 37\lambda^2 + 34\lambda + 6 = 0$

And I don't know how to solve it in exact form to get real and complex solution.

Thank you.

Comment: See [quartic formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_function#General_formula_for_roots).